# how to add constant column in Pypika

Tags: python, sql, pypika

I ran into trouble. I've read through manual to pypika and I haven't found out, how to define constant column.

E.g.

```
SELECT t.id, 
       'constant' as constant_variable 
     FROM example_table t
```

I've tried using PseudoColumn, but it didn't work for me.

```
car = PseudoColumn('CAR') 

   query = Query \
        .from_('test_table') \
        .select(car) 
print(query)
```

The result is

```
SELECT CAR FROM "test_table"
```

Instead of

```
SELECT 'CAR' FROM "test_table"
```

Comment: Not a pypika user so not sure if there's a way to concatenate single quotes around "car". While this probably isn't helpful in your situation, you could simply use any number (such as 1) instead of car.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do it is to use ValueWrapper from pypika.terms. Same as in example above, but instead of PseudoColumn('CAR') use ValueWrapper('CAR', 'alias').

```
from pypika.terms import ValueWrapper
car = ValueWrapper('CAR', 'car') 

query = Query \
        .from_('test_table') \
        .select(car)
```